# Is 수전노 a negative word?

Tags: vocabulary

by that I just want to confirm that it would never be used in a positive way

Answer (score 1):

수전노 : 돈을 지키는 노예 slave keeping money (direct translation)

Making a lower estimate on a person who makes an effort on obtaining
money only and never have pity on other.

@ Simply without a pity. He is not immoral and not irrational. But
there are a lot of stories which tells problems around such person
so that it has more negative feeling rather than positive feeling.